# Android Studio Button doesn't play onClick sound after being pressed too often

Tags: java, android, button, audio

I have a few buttons that play sounds through the mediaplayer everytime you tap them.

If you tap them too often though, they go silent. All of them, no matter what button you hit and it doesn't matter how much time you leave between taps.

Afterwards I have to completely kill the app in order to get sound again.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button bt_kick, bt_closed_hat, bt_clap, bt_snare, bt_subdrop, bt_open_hat, bt_shaker_high, bt_shaker_low;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bt_kick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kick);
        bt_closed_hat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.closed_hat);
        bt_clap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clap);
        bt_snare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.snare);
        bt_subdrop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subdrop);
        bt_open_hat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.open_hat);
        bt_shaker_high = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shaker_high);
        bt_shaker_low = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shaker_low);

        bt_kick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.kick);
                mp.start();
            }
        });

        bt_closed_hat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.closed_hat);
                mp.start();
            }
        });

        bt_clap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.clap);
                mp.start();
            }
        });

        bt_snare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.snare);
                mp.start();
            }
        });

        bt_subdrop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.subdrop);
                mp.start();
            }
        });

        bt_open_hat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.open_hat);
                mp.start();
            }
        });

        bt_shaker_high.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.shaker_high);
                mp.start();
            }
        });

        bt_shaker_low.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.shaker_low);
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not create a new mediaplayer inside each onclick, create the mediaplayer in your oncreate, then manage the lifecycle in the onclick. i.e. stop the old sound and start a new sound.

Comment: i did what you are attempting many years ago it might still be relevant: https://github.com/blundell/soundboardengine/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/com/blundell/soundboard/engine/SoundManager.java :-) you can see that it stops the MediaPlayer, resets it and creates a new one with a new sound.

Comment: I had to create a new MediaPlayer on every onClick so that I can tap multiple buttons after another without them cutting out.

Sadly, neither reset(), stop() or release() helped